# Size a UIViewController's view to parent UIWindow's bounds

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I want to give a `UIViewController`'s `view` a size that is different from the device's screen size. I know I can usually achieve this by adding the view controller as a child view controller of another parent `UIViewController` that has defined a frame for the child, but I am in a situation that seems a little different.

I have a `UIWindow` that only takes up a portion of the screen (it's got a frame that's basically `(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, HEIGHT_LESS_THAN_DEVICE_HEIGHT)`. This window shows up with the proper sizing and positioning when presented. I am setting a view controller as the `rootViewController` of the window, and then presenting the window by setting its `hidden` value to `false`. When this happens, the view controller's view ends up sized to fill the device's screen (i.e. a frame of `(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, DEVICE_HEIGHT)`).

What I would like is for the view controller to inherit its sizing from the `UIWindow` it is set as the root view controller of. Is there a way to do this?

I have also tried overriding `loadView()` and returning a custom-sized view there. Logging the view shows that the view controller's `view` object is correctly sized during `viewDidLoad`, but is overwritten with the default size by `viewWillAppear:`. I would be open to using `loadView()` to size the view controller if inheriting sizing from the window isn't possible, but I don't know how to make the custom size stick.

**Note:** The reason why I am trying to add a view controller to the window is because I want to take advantage of the view controller lifecycle methods such as `viewDidAppear:`, which is why I am not just creating a simple `UIView` and adding it as a subview of the window.

Answer (score -1):

As counter intuitive as it may seem, if you set set self.view.frame on viewWillAppear (IOS 8) or viewDidAppear (IOS 7) you will be able to make it work.

Swift code (IOS 8):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Banner style size, for example
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50) 
}
```

For IOS 7, I had to use viewDidAppear, which is obviously an unsatisfactory solution. So I had to start the view with alpha = 0.0 and set alpha = 1.0 on viewDidAppear, after modifying self.view.frame.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems like a good workaround for the problem, but not exactly the path I want to take. Definitely seems like a worthwhile strategy, but I am interested in seeing if there's a way to have the view controller grab this information from it's environment instead of from default values.

Comment: On viewDidAppear you have access to the window object (self.view.window). You can just set self.view.frame to match the window's frame. You can also send the parameters to you controller, before setting it as rooViewController of your new window.

Comment: We should really not hard code frame size via `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50) `, this will not adjust to different screen sizes.